# Data with auto increment Trigger return from MongoDB is different from what I expect

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

The sampleId is not the required input from the frontend and it is incremented by the Trigger in MongoDB. When I use my backend function like below to find the data that I saved, in the console it only return me with these data except the sampleId. I wonder why is that happening? I thought the sampleId data should also be retrieved back to me.

The function that I use to find the data that I saved before:

```
async function create(sampleParam) {
    const sample = new Sample(sampleParam);
    // save sample
    const saved = await sample.save();
    const created = await Sample.findOne({_id: saved._id});
    console.log(created);
    return await created;
}
```

The data that appeared in console after I call the function:

```
{
  _id: 64a8ddcd768bc5f8157005e6,
  productName: 'Vial 2ml(US) Type1',
  OracleItemNum: 8110000008,
  batchSize: 823248,
  numCntrRecv: 11,
  aqlLevel: 'II',
  createdDate: 2023-07-08T03:53:49.149Z,
  __v: 0
}
```

The code of my data model in Node.js for MongoDB is like this below:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const schema = new Schema({
    productName: { type: String, required: true },
    OracleItemNum: { type: Number, required: true },
    batchSize: {type: Number, required:true},
    numCntrRecv: {type: Number, required:true},
    aqlLevel: { type: String, required: true },
    sampleId: { type: Number},
    createdDate: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});


schema.set('toJSON', {
    virtuals: true,
    versionKey: false,
    transform: function (doc, ret) {
        delete ret._id;
        delete ret.hash;
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Sample', schema);
```

The data in the mongoDB looks like this:
[image: The data in the mongoDB looks like this]